# update data base with mariaDB python

Tags: python, mariadb

I am trying to update a data base with mariaDb command. I have used Mysql before with no problems and have checked my script for the mariDb script but when I run it python is stating the following

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE id = 2' at line 1

my script is below can someone please see what I am doing wrong

```
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute ("""UPDATE heating SET garage=%s WHERE id = 2""", (garageTemp))
    except () as e:
        print (e)
```

This is within a function and the garageTemp is a variable taken from part of the full program

Answer (score 0):

Typical got this working just after posting the question. Did not realise I could not put the id = 2 within the statement.

So the following works

```
("""UPDATE heating SET garage=%s WHERE id=%s""", (garageTemp, 2))
```

Comment: Perhaps the first would have worked with `(garageTemp,)` -- to distinguish between creating an array and parenthesizing an expression??